# Regex for filename match

Tags: find

I am struggling to write a regex to use with UNIX find that matches filenames that begin with atdw-AU and then in the rest of the file name have an underscore 7 numerical digits followed by  .jpg or .jpeg

Example to match;

atdw-AU0424646-5fa8c5c54782b49f7d4bf487_1249545.jpg

and not not match;

atdw-AU0424646-5fa8c5c54782b49f7d4bf487.jpg

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '^.*atdw-.+_[0-9]{7}.jpe?g'
```